# How to get html input file type properties in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to Catch upload file properties array in javascript. Is this possible to do in javascript?

Detail Requirement:
 I have html form,which is submitted by javascript function and now i want to add one more field **upload file** in that form but how can that **upload file array** can be send via **javascript function** to my **php script**

```
$('#save').click(function(){        
    var filearray = new Array();
    var file = $("#file")[0].files[0];
    filearray["filename"] = file.name;
    filearray["filesize"] = file.size;
    filearray["fileType"] = file.type;
    filearray["fileTemp"] = file.tmp_name;
    filearray["fileError"] = file.error;
});
```

i am not getting attribute **tmp_name** and **error** in javascript because it generate when file is on server but i am doing this on client side.

Comment: You need to give more details abour your scenario.

Comment: Can u post your javascript function from which you are submitting the form?

Comment: actually code is lengthy so i cant post here , javascript fucntion send an ajax request to php script

Comment: If you can use HTML5 you will find the answer in the File API - http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/ - But the tmp_name and error is totally useless on client-side. Because the tmp_name is the actual name of the file on the server and your file is not yet uploaded and you cant get an error if you did not yet upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File attributes **tmp_name** and **error** generated when the file is on server

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var extension = new Array(".jpg",".jpeg",".JPEG",".JPG",".PNG",".png",".ico",".ICO",".GIF",".gif");

function CheckExtension(fieldvalue)
{
        var thisext = fieldvalue.substr(fieldvalue.lastIndexOf('.'));
    for(var i = 0; i < extension.length; i++) {
        if(thisext == extension[i]) { return true; }
        }

    return false;

}
```

pass the fieldvalue as input file value.

Hope this may help you..

Answer (score 0):

### to get file name and extension:

```
var extension = fileName.split('.').pop();
var name = fileName.split('.')[0];
```

### to get File Size:

```
$('#youfiletextbox').bind('change', function() {
  var fileSize = this.files[0].size);
});
```

Comment: and how to make array of other properties of file like name,type,error?

Comment: I added how to get file name, type is nothing but the extension of the file.

Comment: i am not getting attribute tmp_name and error in javascript because it generate when file is on server but i am doing this on client side

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input type="file" class='img-icon' id="qImage" name="qImage1" accept="image/*" onchange="GetFileInfo('qImage')"/>  
function GetFileInfo(imageID) {
        var fileInput = document.getElementById(imageID);
        var fName;
        var fSize;
        var fType;

        var message = "";
        if ('files' in fileInput) {
            if (fileInput.files.length == 0) {
                alert("Please browse for one or more files.");
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
                    var file = fileInput.files[i];
                    if ('name' in file) {
                        fName = file.name;
                    }
                    else {
                        fName = file.fileName;
                    }
                    if ('size' in file) {
                        fSize = file.size;
                    }
                    else {
                        fSize = file.fileSize;
                    }
                    if ('type' in file) {
                        fType = file.type;
                    }
                    else {
                        fType = file.mediaType;
                    }
                }

                var extension = fName.split('.').pop();
                var size = fSize / 1024;

                if(extension == "png" || extension == "jpg" || extension == "svg"){
                    if(size > 5){
                        alert("Image size must be less than 5kb.");
                        document.getElementById(imageID).value = null;
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("Image type must png, jpg or svg and size must be less than 5kb.");
                    document.getElementById(imageID).value = null;
                } 


            }
        } 
        else {
            if (fileInput.value == "") {
                message += "Please browse for one or more files.";
                message += "<br />Use the Control or Shift key for multiple selection.";
            }
            else {
                message += "Your browser doesn't support the files property!";
                message += "<br />The path of the selected file: " + fileInput.value;
            }
            document.getElementById ("info").innerHTML = message;
        }
    }
<div id="info" style="margin-top:20px"></div>
```